# Can't update favicon with JavaScript to make it rotate

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, favicon

I'm following a blog on [how to animate favicon](https://css-tricks.com/the-making-of-an-animated-favicon/). I didn't get it to work, so I've broken it down into several pieces, concluding that the issue is that I'm not updating the favicon with the generated data.

The console tells me that favicon is not defined and the assignment fails.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <base href="/">
  <!-- <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico"> -->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="" width=32px>
</head>

<script>
  window.onload = function () {
    const canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    if (!!context) {
      context.clearRect(0, 0, 32, 32);
      context.beginPath();
      context.moveTo(0, 0); context.lineTo(0, 32);
      context.moveTo(0, 0); context.lineTo(32, 32);
      context.stroke();
      const data = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
      console.log(data);
      favicon.href = data;
    }
  };</script>

<body>
  <canvas width="32" height="32"></canvas>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>

</html>
```

I can see that the data appears in the console (assuming that it's the proper junk of info). However, the next line fails to execute. There's nothing in the blog about how *favicon* is defined and I wonder if it might be doable only in certain browsers/plattforms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it needs to be a reference to the favicon link:

```
<link id=favicon rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
```

Create a reference to it in javascript:

```
const favicon = document.getElementById('favicon');
```

Comment: Ahem... I didn't just copy the code. I actually read and write my own stuff always trying to modify. If you take a look at the sample you'll see that I'm not nearly to his syntax. A tutorial should have all its parts present and there's nothing mentioned about it in his listing. It was **not** "*completely obvious*" to me... I didn't even imagine that an element in HEAD could be referenced by ID. At any rate - your answer is correct and hence accepted. Thanks.

Comment: @DonkeyBanana - i'm sorry i didn't mean to accuse you of copying and pasting, i see that it clearly isn't copied.

Comment: No worries. I'm aware that a lot of people do the copaste dance and I've seen the results of it. I take pride in not doing that. And I got afraid that I somehow communicated (to you and/or others) that I'm a sloppy copaster and wanted to know how to avoid conveying such impression.